# Instagram API - Simplest method of pulling in a single users feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I'm currently setting up a custom widget that will pull our Instagram feed via the Instagram API on our site. What i've done for now is created an App on what's apparently a soon to be deprecated [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

What i've done is manually created an Instagram API access token by disabling the implicit OAuth option and manually visiting [this](https://elfsight.com/service/generate-instagram-access-token/) URL:

This has given me an access token which I use to make AJAX requests in order to get feed items via calling the below URL:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=my_token&count=8

After finding out Instagram are deprecating their API i've been looking into using the FB Graph API to do the same thing. The confusion here is with what's the best way to achieve this.

With the new API I believe the best way is to create a new app that has the permissions for 'instagram_basic'. This 'Grants the ability to read a user's profile info and media.' according to their documentation. I'm not entirely sure this is the right path as I only need access to our companies Instagram feed rather than individual users'.

Is creating an app purely for the functionality of pulling in the feed of one Instagram account the best way of doing this or is there a much simpler approach?

Also i'm assuming here the access token should only be used on the back end of the site ie it should not be exposed in the front end, also that it won't expire as I will be generating it just once...

Thanks

Comment: _“our companies Instagram feed”_ - so that would be an actual Instagram Business Account then, yes? That would mean going via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#read then I suppose.

Comment: I am also interested about the new access token's expiry, did you manage to get a long life token or does it have to be refreshed?

Comment: I used their old API which gives you a life long token